# Overhead of calling GC.GetTotalMemory(false)

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

In the company I work at we have a bunch of web applications in which we display in the website's footer some information useful for the developers (such as the assembly version).

Performance wise (I'm not caring for the UX aspect of it), would it be a bad idea to show the memory usage by calling `GC.GetTotalMemory(false)`? Should I worry having this call performed on every request?

Comment: I think its a relatively cheap operation, however if you are concerned about performance you could cache it somewhere and update it periodically instead of working it into web requests.

Comment: How does it improve user experience?

Comment: A handful of microseconds max, you can't get a warranty here.  Very hard to imagine that you can't figure this out by yourself.

Comment: @dotctor It doesn't.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for answering. Why it's *very hard to imagine that you can't figure out by yourself*? I've assumed that it wouldn't be a problem since I'm passing `false`, but being sure is another story.

Comment: So it is a bad idea. Number of online users or time it takes to process the request would be more helpful than memory usage for end users.

Comment: @dotctor This is not an [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com) question, I'm not caring for the UX aspect of it.

Comment: I think, any metric, or any tool, that will make the developers of your project consider and monitor the performance of yhe application is very, very valuable. We had a major failure because of a performance issue last week which prevented a bank with millions of customers from serving their customers for 3 hours. This could have been avoided if total memory consumption and CPU usage could be monitored by the developers.

Comment: talles, can you see who is downvoting? We could ask them why..

Answer (score 2):

I got curious when I saw your question since it was not the regular stuff, and decided to give it a try.

Created a simple web site and in default.aspx filled almost 1 GB of small objects (10 million byte arrays with 64 bytes each) into the heap, then called GC.GetTotalMemory 100 times and before each time by adding a new object so that if there is any cached value, it would be obsolete.

The average execution time for GC.GetTotalMemory(false) was 0,000687 milliseconds!

I have a Win 7 64 bit 2 cpu (8 core total) HP with 8 GB RAM.

I think, your developers will have a good metric down there :)

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private List<object> objects = new List<object>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            objects.Add(new byte[64]);
        }

        double averageDuration = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            objects.Add(new byte[64]);
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Response.Write("Total memory: " + GC.GetTotalMemory(false) + " / ");
            sw.Stop();
            averageDuration += sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            Response.Write("Duration: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + "<br/>");
        }

        Response.Write("Average Duration: " + (averageDuration / 100));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your calculation for average duration doesn't look right.

Comment: Does this report the right memory usage? Looks like `objects` can easily be optimized out. Also, as Brian says, an average involves a division...

Comment: Yes, it gives a very good approximation, as it is stated in the documentation on MSDN. In my case,it gave values very close to (and incrementing) Total memory: 828320824, I am editing the code to write the returned value.